# How to get all the http requests sent from a valid url?

Tags: php, html

I have several URLs. I have to check the number of http requests from those URLs. We can get HTTP response from current page by `get_all_header` in php. But is there any way to find out number of HTTP requests from a URL (without using any API)?

Comment: From PHP only? No. You would need to read the server logs.

Comment: it may php or javascript or any other. I want to record them in a file or array.

Comment: You can't access requests from other devices sent to a webserver directly in php. The webservers logs can give you this information

Comment: You would have to open the url, get all assets, run all javascript and see what connections are made; you would have to simulate a browser on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php ? It fetches all the headers from definied URL.